# Can Low gradient norm be an indicator of a problem in my deep learning model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, deep-residual-networks

Anyone knows how to troubleshoot deep learning model training through gradient norm ? I am reproducing a research paper work but I'm not getting same results as theirs. I am training a model of 16 residual blocks with ReLU activation function, categorical cross entropy, StepLRScheduler and Adam optimizer. number of epochs = 10, batch size = 12, starting lr = 0.001 and then it decays by 0.5 every epoch after the 6th epoch. the dataset is imbalanced so I tried weighted loss and focal loss and nothing seems to work. I tried to troubleshoot the training by computing the gradient norm every 1000 batch and noticed the values are small (around 1e-4) is this normal or can this be an indicator of some problem ?

[image: Total Gradient Norm]

I looked for references that may help in interpreting gradient norm and how to use it to troubleshoot my model but I found nothing.
My second question is : Does anyone have interesting ressources on how to troubleshoot and diagnose deep learning models ?

Comment: Does your training loss decreases over time? It is a better indication of wheter you are optimizing well your model or not rather than the gradient norm. I would argue that the norm of the gradient is not really relevant as it is a mean over many parameters grads that should be close to 0 for most of them.

Comment: First of all thank you for your response, yes the validation loss decreases over time but the model fails to reproduce the same results as stated in the research paper + I couldn't get satisfactory precision nor recall values (always < 0.5) it's like my model performs worse than a random model

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that many research papers performance are not reproducible. Are you far from the target?

Comment: Yes I am, they got a top accuracy of 0.9 while the maximum value I got is 0.54